# convert string variable to hexadecimal

Tags: c#, .net

i have a string variable that contains a hex value. What i want is to convert this string to an integer so i can subtract this value with another hex value. Code below:

```
string im_cmd = new string(ch3) //ch3 is char array type (ch3[])
im_cmd = myArray[position, 0]; // get the hex value from myArray
int vh = Convert.ToInt32(im_cmd);
int diff = vh - pc;
im_cmd = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(diff.ToString(), 16), 2);
```

for instance, if im_cmd = 00400004, then the variable vh = 0x00061a84
what i want is `vh = 0x00400004` so i can subtract vh with the pc value that contains only hex values.
any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614(v=vs.110).aspx) method has an overload where you can supply the base:

```
int vh = Convert.ToInt32(im_cmd, 16);
```

*UPDATE:*
Hint: Instead of

```
im_cmd = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(diff.ToString(), 16), 2);
```

you can use

```
im_cmd = String.Format("{0:x}", diff);
```

to output the integer as a HEX-string.

Comment: it works!
i also tried 
int vh = int.Parse(im_cmd,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
and is the same result as your answer!
thanks again!